# Cookies being automatically empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web

I have cookies named empid which stores the id of employee i am going to use. But whenever i try to get the value of any cookie its value is set to null automatically and this code is from a partial class which is inherited by page . What if i want to create a class that contains all the database related code and want to use it in everypage

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString()))
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            try
            {

                cn.Open();
                SqlDataReader conReader;
                conReader = null;
                mycomment.Text = Response.Cookies["empid"].Value;
                // cmd.CommandText = "Select * from comments where c_from = " + Response.Cookies["cid"] + " and c_to = "+ Response.Cookies["empid"].ToString();
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                mycomment.Text = cmd.CommandText;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                conReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (conReader.Read())
                {
                    mycomment.Text += conReader[3].ToString();

                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting Cookies from the `Response` object - which is the outgoing cookies set, not the `Request` object which is the set of cookies coming from the client.

Change it to `mycomment.Text = this.Request.Cookies["empid"].Value`.

I also see you're forming SQL commands by using String Concatenation without any sanitation. **DO NOT EVER DO THIS**. Instead use parameters:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE c_from = @from AND c_to = @to";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", this.Request.Cookies["cid"].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to"  , this.Request.Cookies["empid"].Value);
```